# Translate a POST request from POSTMAN using R httr::POST

Tags: r, postman, httr

I try to make a post request to my API using **R**. In Postman it looks like this:
[image]

[image]

And I make a request from httr package, but it get errors. My code here:

```
library(digest)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

# Declare parameter
url <- "https://api.bizfly.vn/crm/_api/base-table/struct"

nonce <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time())) %>% 
    round()

BIZFLY_PROJECT_TOKEN <- "............"
API_SECRET <- "..........."

hmac_512 <- hmac(key = API_SECRET,
                 object = paste0(nonce, BIZFLY_PROJECT_TOKEN),
                 algo = 'sha512')

headers <- c("cb-access-key" = "...........",
             "cb-project-token" = "..........",
             "cb-access-timestamp" = paste0(nonce),
             "cb-access-sign" = hmac_512,
             "Content-Type" = "application/json")

query <- list("table" = "data_customer")

data <- httr::POST(url = url,
                   body = "table = data_customer",
                   add_headers(.headers = headers))
data_content <- content(data, as = 'parsed')
```

When i open output "data_content", it get this:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: "table = data_customer" is not valid json, try with body='{"table" : "data_customer"}'

Comment: Tks @Billy34 , it's helpful to me